# How do I create a popup from Flex without a browser toolbar?

Tags: apache-flex, popup, externalinterface, navigatetourl

I'm trying to launch a popup window from Flex, but the popup window needs to have certain properties as one can usually specify with the JavaScript window.open.  For example, the popup window should not have a browser toolbar or URL box.

I've tried using navigateToURL, which works fine, but I can't find a way to specify the popup window properties.

I've tried using ExternalInterface.call, but the popup gets blocked when calling window.open directly, or even creating a custom JS function that calls window.open.

Help!

Thanks!

Comment: Please just don't. Pop-ups without toolbar/addressbar are a security and usability disaster, which is why some browsers now won't let you do it full stop. Most things people used to use chromeless popups for are nowadays typically done with in-page popup elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's even possible to disable the browser toolbar or URL box in a lot of browsers (I certainly do not allow it on any of the browsers I use).

If you're using navigateToURL, why can't the page you're opening run the JS to try to disable the toolbar and URL? I think you can also attach attributes to the URL if you wanted to send properties over.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most JS-compatible browsers support styling the popup via the window.open method, but Flex doesn't seem to support this...  and I'm not sure of a way to do it on the fly (after the window has been opened)

Comment: Take a look at this page: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/communityengine/index.cfm?event=showdetails&productId=2&postId=5221 
You can pass javascript parameters to the window.open() function. Just replace with the ones you want to use. Once again, such functionality (removing address bars, etc) will not work for any browser I am using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PopUpManager class of Flex for creating custom pop up box.

This example may help you. [Custom PopUp](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/06/creating-custom-pop-up-windows-with-the-popupmanager-class/)

Comment: I'm not looking to create an in-flex popup... I'm looking for a browser window popup.

Answer (score 0):

Check out AndrewT's blog about checking for popup blockers. 
If not blocked, then use ExternalInterface; otherwise use the flex popup.

[Detecting Popup Blockers](http://www.insideria.com/2008/02/quick-flex-tip-detecting-popup.html)

Or better yet, use SWFAddress v2.3 (javascript and AS3) modules. The AS3 has SWFAddress::popup() facade that proxies the poup call to the javascript. You can modify the SWFAdress.js popup function to use Andrew's logic and return a status. This would be a best practice: leveraging superlative SWFAddress library from flex for deeplinking, google analytics, and popups.